# Cufon + SelectBoxIt combination ads three dots when I have 2 or more words in option

Tags: javascript, jquery, cufon

I have a code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('#select-stuff', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro' });
            Cufon.refresh('#select-stuff'); 
</script>

<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){

          // loading selectBoxIt
          var select = $("select");
          select.selectBoxIt();

          // code to fix reloading cufon on select change in select box
          refreshCufon();
          select.change(function() {
            refreshCufon();
          });          
          function refreshCufon() {
           Cufon.replace('#select-stuff', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro' });
           Cufon.refresh();
          }

        });
</script>
```

and it works but when I have e.g. 2 or more words in the option it goes wrong and instead of the words it add s three dots like this:

[image]

or

[image]

So it doesn't matter how many words tere are. it somehow replace the last word with three dots.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Any idea? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Post a link to your code or post more of the code here. Although remove `text-overflow: ellipsis` should do the trick, there appears to be another issue since there's plenty of horizontal space for "Year of the change" to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style rel="stylesheet">
  .selectboxit-text {
    text-overflow: clip;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: seems to be working with clip. Thanks ;). Will tick/bounty in 13 hours or so ;D

Comment: This should now be fixed with the latest SelectBoxIt release.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [default `.css` file](https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/blob/master/src/stylesheets/jquery.selectBoxIt.css) provided with selectBoxIt, it contains an entry:

```
/* Button Text */
.selectboxit-text {
  ...
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  ...
}
```

which adds the ellipsis (three dots) automatically when text is longer that the container. It's possible that changing the `text-overflow` will fix your issue, but it's hard to tell more without actual code.

Comment: just remove/comment that line in the style.

Comment: Any more elegant solution?

Comment: set `text-overflow: clip;` in your css.